# Justice delayed

Tags: traffic, new-york-state, court, covid-19, criminal-procedure

I just rec'd. a summons to have a pre-trial conference re.- a traffic ticket that is dated > 4 yrs. ago (turn w/o signaling).  I have no recollection of it.  Presumably, the NY municipality will claim that adjudication was deferred on account of COVID; but the COVID emergency ended long ago. Can I expect compliance from the prosecutor or from the judge if I will represent myself and demand that the case be dropped? Is there a legal principle that I could articulate that would help me? Justice delayed....

Comment: Was this a camera. or were you stopped?  Your question is liable to be voted closed unless you can make it generic about statute of limitations on traffic offenses.

Comment: I recommend you Google "Statute of Limitations traffic violation NY state".  (*or similar key words...*)  There is a lot of information out there and it's likely that you won't get an answer here.

Comment: Don't bother googling "statute of limitations." It's not really relevant here.

Answer (score 3):

Ask a lawyer to consider moving for a dismissal based on a violation of your right to a [speedy trial](https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/laws/CPL/30.30).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

### There is no [statute of limitations](https://legalbeagle.com/6327801-statute-traffic-offenses-new-york.html) on traffic violations in New York

4 months, 4 years, 40 years - it doesn't matter; the state can pursue a case whenever it wants.

Comment: This isn't a statute-of-limitations question; it's a speedy-trial question.